# performance test script for an EPP application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, epp

Can we perform load tests on EPP applications? The application is a Windows batch file that interacts with the server. Which performance testing tool would be suitable for use? I need some help with this.

Comment: What's the scenario? Run .bat file on multiple machines?

Comment: The basic goal of the test is to generate load on the server. And the application used to send request is an EPP application (is a batch file) which uses TCP protocol for communication.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is "interacts". If your goal is to simulate hunderds/thousands of Windows machines concurrencty running the batch file the easiest way would be replicating the network traffic generated by these .batch files so you could replay it at scale.

So you need to analyze the [network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) which is(are) under the hood of the batch file used for communication with the server and check if the network footprint can be simulated using JMeter's built-in [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), if the protocol communication can be replayed - you can just increase the number of threads (virtual users) in JMeter's [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to simulate multiple simultaneous batches execution.

If batch file uses [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol for interacting with the server - you will be even able to record the traffic using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), see [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more details.

It is also possible to kick off multiple batches instance using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) but in this case you won't get reasonable metrics and KPIs

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response. The goal of my test is to generate load on the server and the protocol used by EPP for communication is TCP.

Comment: Then you can easily simulate the TCP requests using either [TCP Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter/) which is available out of the box or [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, for your response. I will follow these steps and see how it goes.